# Processing plugin Python error on startup of QGIS 2.8.1

Tags: qgis, python, error, qgis-processing, qgis-2.8

I've been running QGIS with no issues for several versions now, but after I upgraded to 2.8.1 Wien I had trouble running two plugins: qgis2leaf (which I believe depends on Processing) and Processing.

From looking around online I think my issue has to do with the version of Python QGIS is accessing. After completely uninstalling QGIS (including deleting my user file and registry key) I reinstalled with OSGEO4W in a new folder, but I still get the same issue. I have python installed for ArcGIS, but I'd rather not mess with it as this is an enterprise PC and reinstalling ArcGIS is a much bigger pain than QGIS.

Any ideas would be helpful, as I've run out of things to try. Here is my error message on startup:

```
Couldn't load plugin 'processing' from ['C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python', 'C:/Users/CHamby/.qgis2/python', 'C:/Users/CHamby/.qgis2/python/plugins', 'C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins', 'C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg', 'C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado-4.0.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\backports.ssl_match_hostname-3.4.0.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\certifi-14.05.14-py2.7.egg', 'c:\osgeo4~1\apps\python27\lib\site-packages\python_dateutil-2.1-py2.7.egg', 'c:\osgeo4~1\apps\python27\lib\site-packages\six-1.3.0-py2.7.egg', 'C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\site-packages', 'C:\OSGEO4~1\bin\python27.zip', 'C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\DLLs', 'C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib', 'C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\plat-win', 'C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk', 'C:\OSGEO4~1\bin', 'C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27', 'C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages', 'C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL', 'C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\markupsafe-0.23-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytz-2012j-py2.7.egg', 'C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32', 'C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib', 'C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin', 'C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode', 'C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd-0.9.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt-0.7.5-py2.7.egg', 'C:/Users/CHamby/.qgis2//python', 'C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\qgis\python\plugins\fTools\tools']


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 196, in loadPlugin
    __import__(packageName)
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 478, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\__init__.py", line 29, in 
    from processing.tools.general import *
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 478, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 28, in 
    from processing.core.Processing import Processing
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 478, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 48, in 
    from processing.algs.qgis.QGISAlgorithmProvider import QGISAlgorithmProvider
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 478, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\QGISAlgorithmProvider.py", line 99, in 
    from RasterLayerStatistics import RasterLayerStatistics
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 478, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\RasterLayerStatistics.py", line 35, in 
    from processing.tools import raster
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 478, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\tools\raster.py", line 29, in 
    import numpy
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 478, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 137, in 
    import add_newdocs
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 478, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 9, in 
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 478, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 4, in 
    from type_check import *
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 478, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 8, in 
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 478, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 5, in 
    import multiarray
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 478, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.


Python version:
2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]


QGIS version:
2.8.1-Wien Wien, exported

Python path: ['C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python', u'C:/Users/CHamby/.qgis2/python', u'C:/Users/CHamby/.qgis2/python/plugins', 'C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins', 'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\tornado-4.0.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\backports.ssl_match_hostname-3.4.0.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\certifi-14.05.14-py2.7.egg', 'c:\\osgeo4~1\\apps\\python27\\lib\\site-packages\\python_dateutil-2.1-py2.7.egg', 'c:\\osgeo4~1\\apps\\python27\\lib\\site-packages\\six-1.3.0-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.2\\Lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\bin\\python27.zip', 'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\bin', 'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\Python27', 'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\PIL', 'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\markupsafe-0.23-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\pytz-2012j-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\wx-2.8-msw-unicode', 'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\xlrd-0.9.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\xlwt-0.7.5-py2.7.egg', u'C:/Users/CHamby/.qgis2//python', 'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\qgis\\python\\plugins\\fTools\\tools']
```

Comment: Are the actual plugins themselves deleted? Plugins are normally installed in _C:\Users\You\.qgis2\python\plugins_.

Comment: Interestingly, there's only an 'expressions' folder in /python/ here. The installer placed my plugins in C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python\plugins\processing. I'm surprised a completely fresh installation would not have done this correctly. I tried copying plugins over to this folder, but it doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: That is strange, hopefully others can advise about this. I haven't installed QGIS 2.8 so can't really test it.

Comment: I did one more full reinstall and that seemed to fix the missing folder problem - the plugins now appear in my user folder. Unfortunately the error message remains the same...

Comment: Perhaps downgrade your [Processing plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/processing/) manually to an earlier version, replace this processing folder with the one in your _\.qgis2\python_ directory and see if that helps?

Comment: I tried reverting to Processing 2.2 and got the same error message unfortunately. Based on the error message I'm wondering if there's some mismatch with 32 vs 64 bit versions somewhere here. Could that C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\ reference be throwing it off?

Comment: I would probably just go back to the previous version of QGIS that worked =). There may be a mismatch with the 32/64 bit versions but I'm not qualified enough to help. Hopefully others can advise.

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  I installed QGIS via OSGeo4W onto a machine with existing python installs (both 32 and 64 bit).  Anyone know of a solution that does not require using the 32 bit version of QGIS? And to clarify, the issue stems from a missing numpy dll (which in my case is there, but fails to import).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this in the end, though I still don't know for sure why I had this problem.

I completely uninstalled QGIS, including the deletion of my user data and the registry key. I then went with the standalone 32-bit QGIS installer, and did a basic install. This did the trick!

Again, I don't know why I had the issue as I have a 64 bit operating system, but in case anyone has my problem this solution worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me too. Same scenario